# View not displaying in navigation hierarchy when interrupted by UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

When I hit the save button in the second level of my navigation hierarchy, I pop the view controller (animated) and then present a local notification.

The problem is that when my application delegate receives a local notification it pushes a third view controller (not animated).

Since a new view controller is pushed as the old one is being popped, the new one is on top of the stack while the view of the old one is displayed.

The notifications are usually scheduled, but I observed some occasional odd behavior and this is the cause.